# Send To Messenger button isn't showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to integrate the [Send To Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin) button to my web app. The problem is in **localhost** environment, the button does render, but in **staging** environment it doesn't. (even though the two environments use the same `page_id` and `messenger_app_id`)

This is the code of the Send To Messenger button:

```
<div
class="fb-send-to-messenger"
page_id="568015096933xxx"
messenger_app_id="402876686862xxx"
color="blue"
size="xlarge"
data-ref="123456"
cta_text="SUBSCRIBE_TO_UPDATES"></div>
```

- In localhost, the button is showing:
  [image]
  [HTML of the rendered button.](https://gist.github.com/sonlexqt/bb247dc3adbee5b41b92a2d7ae208dd0)
- In staging, the button is not showing:
  [image]
  [HTML of the rendered button.](https://gist.github.com/sonlexqt/af00b46139d41d7da8f90d528af42302)

**Note:** I did add the staging website's domain to the Facebook page's whitelist sites.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Have you logged the event described in the 'Event Subscription' section of the docs?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin

Comment: @amuramoto I didn't see any errors in the console. Logging the event didn't help because the button isn't even showing. I posted my work-around for this, hope it helps others.

Comment: @sonlexqt are you still facing the issue? Can you host it somewhere and share the url?

Comment: @GijoVarghese It's working with my workaround, you can see it [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182455/send-to-messenger-button-isnt-showing/51280876#51280876)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my "dirty" workaround for this issue... Basically I copied the [HTML of rendered button](https://gist.github.com/sonlexqt/bb247dc3adbee5b41b92a2d7ae208dd0) and built a component from it.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import { LANGUAGE } from '/imports/constants';
import { compose, withProps, withHandlers } from 'recompose';

const SendToMessengerEnhancer = compose(
  withProps(() => {
    const user = Meteor.user();
    const language = (user.language === LANGUAGE.EN || user.language === LANGUAGE['EN-US']) ? 'en_US' : 'vi_VN';
    const { appId, pageId } = Meteor.settings.public.facebook;
    const ctaText = 'SUBSCRIBE_TO_UPDATES';
    const color = 'blue';
    const size = 'xlarge';
    return {
      language,
      appId,
      pageId,
      ctaText,
      userId: Meteor.userId(),
      color,
      size,
    };
  }),
  withHandlers({
    createMarkup: ({
      language,
      appId,
      pageId,
      ctaText,
      userId,
      color,
      size,
    }) => () => {
      const originEncoded = encodeURIComponent(Meteor.absoluteUrl());
      const domain = window.location.hostname;
      const channel = `http://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/xaOI6zd9HW9.js?version=42#cb=fab5aacb255238&domain=${domain}&origin=${originEncoded}f1c42e700a608a4&relation=parent.parent`;
      const channelEncoded = encodeURIComponent(channel);
      const html = `
      <div
        class="fb-send-to-messenger fb_iframe_widget"
        page_id="${pageId}"
        messenger_app_id="${appId}"
        color="${color}"
        size="${size}"
        enforce_login="false"
        data-ref="${userId}"
        cta_text="${ctaText}"
        fb-xfbml-state="rendered"
        fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=&amp;color=blue&amp;container_width=532&amp;cta_text=${ctaText}&amp;enforce_login=false&amp;locale=${language}&amp;messenger_app_id=${appId}&amp;page_id=${pageId}&amp;ref=${userId}&amp;sdk=joey&amp;size=${size}">
          <span
            style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 256px; height: 68px;">
            <iframe
              name="f3769e54c3c93e8"
              width="1000px"
              height="1000px"
              frameborder="0"
              allowtransparency="true"
              allowfullscreen="true"
              scrolling="no"
              allow="encrypted-media"
              title="fb:send_to_messenger Facebook Social Plugin"
              src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/plugins/send_to_messenger.php?app_id=&amp;channel=${channelEncoded}&amp;color=${color}&amp;container_width=532&amp;cta_text=${ctaText}&amp;enforce_login=false&amp;locale=${language}&amp;messenger_app_id=${appId}&amp;page_id=${pageId}&amp;ref=${userId}&amp;sdk=joey&amp;size=${size}"
              style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 256px; height: 68px;"
              class=""
            ></iframe>
          </span>
        </div>
      `;
      return {
        __html: html,
      };
    },
  }),
);

const SendToMessengerView = ({ createMarkup }) => <div className="send-to-messenger-btn" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;

export default SendToMessengerEnhancer(SendToMessengerView);
```

**Some notes:**

- My app is built on [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) that's why you'll see `Meteor.settings`, `Meteor.user()`, etc
- I use [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) to help building HOCs

Hope this helps others who having the same issue.